# My Command argument not working in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I am experiencing a problem on Tkinter. The output shows me "

> 'Qr_Code' object has no attribute 'generate'

I am making QR code generator, but for now I am stuck in function calling by command argument.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Qr_Code:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry('720x720+250+250')
        self.root.title('QR Code Generaotr | Devoloped by Sanyal')
        
        title = Label(self.root, text = '   Welcome to QR Code Generator', font = ('outfit'), bg="#414aff", fg="white", anchor='w').place(x=5,y=10, relwidth=1)
        
        #================== Variables ==================
        self.var_txt_ID=StringVar()
        self.var_txt_name=StringVar()
        self.var_txt_amt=IntVar()
        self.var_txt_paid=IntVar()
        self.var_txt_balance=IntVar()
        
        #==================== Client Details ===============
        client_frame = Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief = RIDGE, bg='white')
        client_frame.place(x=20,y=50, width=400, height=650)
        cframe_title = Label(client_frame, text='Bill Information', font = ('outfit'), bg="black", fg="white").place(x=0,y=0, relwidth=1)
        
        client_ID = Label(client_frame, text = 'Bill Number', font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", anchor='w').place(x=5,y=60)
        client_name = Label(client_frame, text = 'Name', font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", anchor='w').place(x=5,y=110)
        client_amt = Label(client_frame, text = 'Amount', font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", anchor='w').place(x=5,y=160)
        client_paid = Label(client_frame, text = 'Amount Paid', font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", anchor='w').place(x=5,y=210)
        client_Balance = Label(client_frame, text = 'Amount Balance', font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", anchor='w').place(x=5,y=270)
        
        txt_ID = Entry(client_frame, font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", textvariable=self.var_txt_ID).place(x=200,y=60, width=150)
        txt_name = Entry(client_frame, font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", textvariable=self.var_txt_name).place(x=200,y=110, width=150)
        txt_amt = Entry(client_frame, font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", textvariable=self.var_txt_amt).place(x=200,y=160, width=150)
        txt_paid = Entry(client_frame, font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", textvariable=self.var_txt_paid).place(x=200,y=210, width=150)
        txt_Balance = Entry(client_frame, font = ('outfit'), bg="white", fg="black", textvariable=self.var_txt_balance).place(x=200,y=270, width=150)
        
        gen_qr_button = Button(client_frame, text='Generate QR Code',font = ('outfit',10), bg='#414aff', fg='white', relief=RAISED, command=self.generate).place(x=100, y=350)
        gen_qr_button = Button(client_frame, text='Clear', font = ('outfit',10), bg='#414aff', fg='white', relief=RAISED).place(x=250, y=350)
        
        self.msg = "QR Code Generated Sucessfully...!!!"
        self.lbl_msg = Label(client_frame, text = self.msg, font = ('outfit',15,'italic'), bg="white", fg="green").place(y=400, relwidth=1)
        
        #========================== QR Code ========================
        qr_frame = Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief = RIDGE, bg='white')
        qr_frame.place(x=450,y=180, width=240,height=400)
        qframe_title = Label(qr_frame, text='QR Code', font = ('outfit'), bg="black", fg="white",).place(x=0,y=0, height=25, relwidth=1)
        
        self.no_qr= Label(qr_frame, text='No QR Code\nAvailable', font = ('outfit'), bg = '#414aff', fg = 'white',relief=RIDGE).place(x=50,y=110,width=140, height= 175)
        
        #==================== QR Generation ======================
        def generate(self):
            print(self.var_txt_ID.get())
        
root = Tk()
obj = Qr_Code(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I am expecting to call the function by,  command= self.generate keyword, but I am getting error.

Comment: You have indented the `def generate(` one level too far, so it's actually local to `__init__()` rather than a method of the class.